# gradient of the normalized cross product

Tags: partial-derivative

Can someone be so kind to verify the derivation of the gradient of a normalized cross product?

I have translated the pseudo code from "[Position Based Dynamics](https://matthias-research.github.io/pages/publications/posBasedDyn.pdf)" to working code, but the Bending Constraint Projection section gives me headaches - last page, right column.

$$\boldsymbol{n}=\frac{ \boldsymbol{p_1} \times \boldsymbol{p_2}}{\vert \boldsymbol{p_1} \times \boldsymbol{p_2}\vert}$$
$$\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{n}}{\partial \boldsymbol{p_1}}=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial n_x}{\partial p_{1_x}} & \frac{\partial n_x}{\partial p_{1_y}} & \frac{\partial n_x}{\partial p_{1_z}} \\\
\frac{\partial n_y}{\partial p_{1_x}} & \frac{\partial n_y}{\partial p_{1_y}} & \frac{\partial n_y}{\partial p_{1_z}} \\\
\frac{\partial n_z}{\partial p_{1_x}} & \frac{\partial n_z}{\partial p_{1_y}} & \frac{\partial n_z}{\partial p_{1_z}}\end{bmatrix}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\vert \boldsymbol{p_1} \times \boldsymbol{p_2}\vert}
(
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & p_{2_z} & -p_{2_y} \\\
-p_{2_z} & 0 & p_{2_x} \\\
p_{2_y} & -p_{2_x} & 0\end{bmatrix}
)
+(\boldsymbol{n}(\boldsymbol{n} \times \boldsymbol{p_2})^{ \mathrm{ T } })
$$
Shorter and for both arguments we have:
$$\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{n}}{\partial \boldsymbol{p_1}}=\quad \frac{1}{\vert \boldsymbol{p_1} \times \boldsymbol{p_2}\vert}(-\tilde{\boldsymbol{p_2}} + \boldsymbol{n}(\boldsymbol{n} \times \boldsymbol{p_2})^{ \mathrm{ T } })$$
$$\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{n}}{\partial \boldsymbol{p_2}}=-\frac{1}{\vert \boldsymbol{p_1} \times \boldsymbol{p_1}\vert}(-\tilde{\boldsymbol{p_1}} + \boldsymbol{n}(\boldsymbol{n} \times \boldsymbol{p_1})^{ \mathrm{ T } })$$
where $\tilde{\boldsymbol{p}}$ is the matrix with the property $\tilde{\boldsymbol{p}}\boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{p} \times \boldsymbol{x}$

Unfortunately, I don't have the math skills to arrive at the above derivation. If the above is right, I don't know how the authors use these equations to (21)--->(25) in the paper.

$$\boldsymbol{n_1}=\frac{ \boldsymbol{p_2} \times \boldsymbol{p_3}}{\vert \boldsymbol{p_2} \times \boldsymbol{p_3}\vert}$$
$$\Biggl(\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{n_1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{p_3}}\Biggr)^{ \mathrm{ T } }\boldsymbol{n_2} \to \frac{ \color{red}{\boldsymbol{-}}\boldsymbol{p_2} \times \boldsymbol{n_2} + (\boldsymbol{n_1} \times \boldsymbol{p_2})d}{\vert \boldsymbol{p_2} \times \boldsymbol{p_3}\vert}$$

I corrected what I think is missing, a minus sign. The same is true for equation (26-27).
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After a good sleep, and with the help of Wolfram Mathematica I was able to verify that the equations are correct. I basically write the initial statement in its full form and made it equal with the end result / equation. It returned True, so they are correct!

The red minus sign is not missing, I just needed another look.